# Problem in solving optimization problem on Python

Tags: python, optimization

I am trying to solve an optimization problem on Python with Gurobi solver. There is a constraint in which I am trying to multiply a 1×n variable vector with a single column of n×n matrix:

The code is as follows:

```
sigma1m = np.matrix(sigma1)

gamma1 = model.addMVar(n, name="gamma1")

for i in range(n):

    model.addConstr(gamma1 * sigma1m[:,i] == 0)
```

In this case, n=22, sigma1 is a 22×22 covariance matrix obtained from some data (sigma1=dfpart1.cov()). gamma1 is a variable vector consisting of 22 elements.

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Answer (score 0):

error "only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" means, you are assigning an array instead of a scalar,

```
model.addConstr(gamma1 * sigma1m[:,i] == 0)
```

in this line gamma1 might be becoming a scalar instead of a vector, check that